# What is the difference between literal string and Args in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a string parsing function using regex: `fn parse(s: &str) -> Option<MyObj>`. It works when testing with `parse("test string")`. But failed when using `Args`. The failure is that the regex could not matching anything from `s`.

The way I used `Args` is: `args().map(|arg| parse(&arg)).collect()`. I could not see type error here. And `println` in `parse` shows `s` is the same string as "test string".

---

Updated my description. I am not sure if my problem is related with how String and str are different. Because I was using `str` and it still failed.

```rust
extern crate regex;

use regex::Regex;
use std::env::args;

struct IPRange {
    start: u32,
    mask: u8,
}

fn parse_iprange(ipr: &str) -> Option<IPRange> {
    let parser = Regex::new(
        r"^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/(\d+|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})$",
    )
    .unwrap();
    let caps = parser.captures(ipr).unwrap();
    return Some(IPRange { start: 0, mask: 0 });
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<_> = args().map(|arg| parse_iprange(&arg)).collect();
}
```

```
$ RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run 192.168.3.1/24
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.04s
     Running `target/debug/ip_helper 192.168.3.1/24`
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src/libcore/option.rs:345:21
stack backtrace:
   0: std::sys::unix::backtrace::tracing::imp::unwind_backtrace
             at src/libstd/sys/unix/backtrace/tracing/gcc_s.rs:39
   1: std::sys_common::backtrace::_print
             at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:70
   2: std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}
             at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:58
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:200
   3: std::panicking::default_hook
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:215
   4: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:478
   5: std::panicking::continue_panic_fmt
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:385
   6: rust_begin_unwind
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:312
   7: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at src/libcore/panicking.rs:85
   8: core::panicking::panic
             at src/libcore/panicking.rs:49
   9: <core::option::Option<T>>::unwrap
             at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858/src/libcore/macros.rs:10
  10: ip_helper::parse_iprange
             at src/main.rs:18
```

Comment: @Stargateur Updated. Thanks. If I replace the only line in `main` with `parse_iprange("192.168.3.1/24")`, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first item of [`args()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.args.html) is implementation behavior:

> The first element is traditionally the path of the executable, but it can be set to arbitrary text, and may not even exist. This means this property should not be relied upon for security purposes.

So, you should skip it in your case:

```rust
let v: Vec<_> = args().skip(1).map(|arg| parse_iprange(&arg)).collect();
```